# How to precompile my GLSL shader program on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es-3.0

I'm using GLES 3.0 on my iOS app , trying to precompile GLSL shader program, but when I try to get length of the program binary like this:

```
    GLint len;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH, &len);
```

len becomes 0。
this is my code

```
    GLint len;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH, &len);
    int binaryFormat;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_FORMATS, &binaryFormat);
    char *binary = malloc(len);
    glGetProgramBinary(programId, len, &len, &binaryFormat, binary);
```

I try to set len=1024, then I got a glerror after glGetProgramBinary.
Any one have any idea about this ?

Comment: Are you sure the program is linked successfully? The spec states: "When a program object’s
LINK_STATUS is FALSE, its program binary length is zero, and a call to GetProgramBinary
will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error"

Comment: I'm sure my program is linked successfully, I've use the program to draw my scene before.